# SSRS: Subreport margins issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a main report which contains two subreports, let's say SubReportA and SubReportB.

I have set the margins as below for each one:

- Main report: Margins all to 0
- SubreportA: Margins all to 0
- SubreportB: Margins all to 1,5cm

My problem is:

1. SubReportA is printed with a little bottom margin when exporting to PDF. In preview it works ok. SubReportA is the cover so I want margins all set to 0.
2. SubReportB is always printed without margins, that is, all set to 0cm instead of 1,5cm. It happens in preview and when importing it to PDF.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Main report has a page size of 8.5in, 11in. I usually do 0.5in for my margins on both the main report and subreport. Try making the main report and subreports have the same page size and interactive size of 8.5in by 11 and same margins. The body of your subreports should just less than 7.5 inches width and 10 inches length. Are both subreports inside the main report?

Comment: Yes, both subreports are in the same main report. Point 1) was due that I have a footer that is not shown one subReportA but the space occupied by that is there, cannot be used for the rest of the body. Hence that there is only a little margin at the bottom. Regarding point 2) if I set same margins for  main report and subreports, how can I set margins to 0 for main report and subreportA except for subreportB? For subreportB I want a margin of 1,5.

Comment: I don't think subreports use their own page layout info, they defer to the parent.  This is why your subreportB has no margins even when you set it to 1.5 - because the parent has no margins.  It would be the same issue if you set the main report to 11x17 landscape, but the subreport to 8.5x11 portrait - they are both going to come out 11x17 landscape.